# PageView Event missing some deduplication parameters

Tags: facebook, duplicates, ads, facebook-pixel, facebook-ads

How can I add the event_id parameter to my event? Please help!

[image: PageView Event missing some deduplication parameters]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First step should be reading [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events)

My code to generate EventId looks like:

```
...

public static function getEventId()
{
    return self::$eventId;
}

public static function setEventId(): void
{
    self::$eventId = time().'.'.rand(1000000, 9999999);;
}

...
```

Event Id should be send in server event and same in pixel event
Example:

```
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
        {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq( 'init', '<?php echo FacebookCapiSettings::getPixelId(); ?>', {'external_id': '<?php echo $_COOKIE['USERID2']; ?>'<?php echo $userDataString; ?>} );
    fbq( 'track', 'PageView', {}, {eventID: '<?php echo FacebookCapiPageView::getEventId(); ?>'} );
</script>
```